# AzureAD invited guest source "Microsoft Account" cant login

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

i've got one AzureAD and want to invite some guest users.
Guest user with O365-Account or without O365 can login to my AzureAD-Application after accepting my invitation link and I see these users as "Guest" - Source: "External active directory". Everything is ok.

Now I have some users i.e. with email adress like this: example@outlook.com

When I send the invitation to these users and when they accept it, I see these users in AD as "Guest" - Source "Microsoft Account" and then this users can't login to my AzureAD-Application.

Is it not supported that this users with personal Microsoft Account? cant invitited as guest user?

Thanks

Comment: Guests(users with personal account) should be able to login.  And I have tried on my side. I can login in with example@outlook(as a guest and -source Microsoft Account). What is the error message when you login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know [azure active directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview) has two version [V1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview) and [V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)

If you have a look on `V1` you would know it has no privilege for `personal account` which is  `example@outlook.com`. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#who-can-sign-in)

But in `V2` you can do it. It has included some more feature as well.

New version both support

Organizational account (Work account)
School account
Guest account 
Personal  account (`example@outlook.com`)

see the screen shot below:

[image]

> **Note:** So if your invited guest belongs to `@outlook.com` for [`V1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview) it would not work. You could check `V2` [configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-create-new-tenant)  and app [registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) here

**Update:**

You could check your application version in following screen shot:

[image]

If you still have any query please feel free to share here in comment. Thanks and happy coding!

**Update for ROPC:**

Though [`resource owner password credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) ROPC is not recommended as its not secure and does not support MFA and personal account. for example `example@outlook.com` for details take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)

See the screen shot below:

[image]

> **My Recommendation**
>
> Use `grant_type:client_credentials` as following format. See the
>   screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks but how can I check if my Application is V1 or V2?

Comment: @bater I have updated the answer please check and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Hm ok I can see my app in both "App registrations" and "App registrations (Legacy)"...sorry but I am a litte confused...

Comment: @bater yeah in recent update both application can be found at `App registrations`. But have successfully added `guest` user with `@outlook.com` account and login nicely it was restricted before but now its allowed. Can you share which message you are getting ?

Comment: I'm getting following message in postman if I try to login with the @outlook.com user: AADSTS50034: The user account {EmailHidden} does not exist in the xxx-xxx-..... directory.
Here are my postman settings:
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token
grant_type: password
resource: https://graph.microsoft.com
scope: openid
client_id: client_id
client_secret: client_secret
username: ...
password: ...

For all other users this workflow works. As I understand you correctly I have to change my URL to "v2.0" ? But then I have to change the request parameters as well?!

Comment: @bater Are you using ROPC grant_type for your token?

Comment: No, I'm using grant_type: password for the token request.

Comment: @bater See the update2 , That's why I always suggest all to provide more details about the problem. Either change `grant_type` or `account type` your problem will be resolve. Thanks and let me know if you have any more query

Comment: @bater Yes man grant_type:password means your providing user name and password for getting token. Its called `resource owner password credential` `ROPC`. Got it?

Comment: Ok thanks I understand that I can't use "my way" to solve this problem, but what other option do I have to login my user? Is there an example which URL, grant_type etc. I have to use? Is this the right one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow ?

Comment: Yeah You could use `grant_type=client_credentials` look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: Ok yes thanks for the update, it becomes a little clearer for me right now. But there is one problem I have with grant_type: client_credentials. I thought that I use this grant_type if I want to get an token for my app, but I want to get an access token for my user. So if I use client_credentials anyone can login to my app, it is unnecessary to fill out the login form with the correct username and password? you know what I mean? it's quite a bit difficult for me to describe my understanding-problems

Comment: I understand, if you still like to user `ROPC` then you have to go with organizational account like `guestuser@contoso.com` no other  way man.

Comment: Ok I understand that ROPC is not recommended by Microsoft but whats then the best practice to login user or to check the username&password. Thats totally unclear for me right now. But anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @bater Read this article till end and be the master of `Microsoft authentication`. Its tough to clarify in comment. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios

Comment: To get tokens for the user, use authorization code, implicit, or device code flow. Depending on your app. Please avoid using ROPC. There's also on-behalf-of flow for middle tier APIs. There is protocol documentation available, but you will be better off using a library to do the authentication. Most OpenID Connect libraries work with the v2 endpoint.

Comment: @juunas I have already told him about ROPC and also asked him about `client_credentials`. For his specific need referred him official document to figured out his requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I have read the documentation but theres also one problem for me: As I understand all the possibilities to get an token (excluding ROPC) are by prompting the Microsoft Login-Formular. But I/my customer want to have his 'own' customized formular. Or is there something I have overlooked?

Comment: Tell them doing it is against best practices as it means users can't use multi-factor authentication, reducing their security. That's in addition to passing passwords through your systems (refer to recent GSuite incident).

Comment: @juunas Yeah I have tried to tell the user when they wish to implement `ROPC`.

Comment: @bater Glad to hear...Thanks and happy coding!